# Excel: Query attributes from a HTML headings

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I want to extract the attributes values from a heading type in a web page using excel vba. The data I want to scrape from the [webpage](http://www.espanol.spindices.com/) has the following structure:

```html
<div class="index-detail">
  <h5><a href="/indices/equity/dow-jones-sustainability-chile-index-clp" title="DJSI Chile" contentIdentifier="2e9cb165-0cbf-4070-a5ef-dc20bf6219ba" contentType="web-page" contentTitle="Dow Jones Sustainability™ Chile Index (CLP)">DJSI Chile</a></h5>
  <span class="return-value">917.08 </span>
  <span class="daily-change  down ">-0.1% ▼ </span>
</div>
```

Using `getElementsByClassName` and `getElementsByTagName` I've already extracted the heading `<h5>`, however when I print the `innerText` of the heading I get `DJSI Chile`, but I want to get the text inside the attribute `contentTitle` which is `Dow Jones Sustainability™ Chile Index (CLP)`.

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

The code is I'm using is as follows:

```js
Sub myConSP()
    
    ' Declare variables
    Dim oHtmlSP As HTMLDocument
    Dim tSPIndex As HTMLDivElement
    Dim tSPIdx As HTMLDivElement

    ' Load page inside HTMLDocument
    Set oHtmlSP = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.espanol.spindices.com", False
        .send
        oHtmlSP.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    ' Get indices
    Set tSPIndex = oHtmlSP.getElementById("all-indices-slider")

    Set objTitleTag = tSPIndex.getElementsByClassName("index-detail")(0).getElementsByTagName("h5")(0)
    MsgBox objTitleTag.getAttribute("contentTitle").innerText

End Sub
```

Comment: `objTitleTag.getAttribute("contentTitle")`

Comment: How should `objTitleTag` be defined?

Comment: It's whatever you called `innerText` on.  It's always best to show your actual code: makes it easier to make suggestions on what to add.

Comment: Just `MsgBox objTitleTag.getAttribute("contentTitle")` - attributes have values but no `innerText` property

Comment: I get `Invalid use of Null (Error 94)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute is attached to `<a>`, not `<h5>` (sorry that was my mistake in the comments above):

```
Sub TT()

    Dim html As String, d As New HTMLDocument, el

    html = "<div class='index-detail'>" & _
    "<h5><a href='/indices/equity/dow-jones-sustainability-chile-index-clp' " & _
    "title='DJSI Chile' contentIdentifier='2e9cb165-0cbf-4070-a5ef-dc20bf6219ba' " & _
    "contentType = 'web-page' " & _
    "contentTitle='Dow Jones Sustainability™ Chile Index (CLP)'>DJSI Chile</a></h5> " & _
    "<span class='return-value'>917.08 </span> " & _
    "<span class='daily-change  down '>-0.1% ? </span></div>"

    d.body.innerHTML = html

    Set el = d.getElementsByClassName("index-detail")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)

    Debug.Print el.getAttribute("contentTitle")
      ' >>> Dow Jones Sustainability™ Chile Index (CLP)


End Sub
```

Comment: I get it, when I extract the elements by class `index-detail` and then I isolate the heading `<h5>`, the attributes doesn't belong to the heading but to another section that start with `<a...`. Worked fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**CSS selector:**

You could use a css selector of a[contentTitle] to get the element(s) with an `a` tag and a `contenttitle` attribute. You then access the contenttitle attribute.

---

**CSS query:**

Selecting the appropriate element

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

You apply the selector to get a single node with `querySelector`; all matching nodes would be `querySelectorAll`.  You use getAttribute to access the required information.

```
oHtmlSP.querySelector("a[contentTitle]").getAttribute("contentTitle")
```